# Developing a Phone App

Tags: java, android, jquery, iphone, dreamweaver

I want to develop an phone app.the main functionality of this app will be, to let the user to request a Taxi(Cab) , and see all the available  taxis on the google map.

And Now I m really confused , because i don't know which programming language to use .

- I used to make a JAVA SWING apps and i know i can build a phone app for Android  using JAVA,
  the problem is that lately i've seen so many cross-platform frameworks for Mobile development like coronalabs,xamarin they claim that it s easy to use and can generate code for Android & IOS
  also i ve read in forums that  Dreamweaver can do the same thing using jQuery .

can anyone tell me where to start and which language or framework to use according to your personal experience?

Comment: The answer to this question will be primarily opinion based. Please refrain from asking such questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If crossplatform is your thing i'd go with adobe air.
It has the name of a big brand behind it with huge resources, which will help in the end.

Best solution would be to learn the native language of each possible platform(android, ios, firefox os) but if you need something "now" go with adobe air.

Comment: this crossplatform "adobe air" has no limitation while developing??. in other word all the things that i can do with a native language of platform are available using adobe air ?

Comment: No, they are not. Adobe air does it's best to accomodate a lot of widely used features, and since you don't know what really is available it's unlikely you'd miss them.
Adobe air is probaly suited enough for your needs.